# Synergy (mouse and keyboard sharing tool) sends wrong keys: ő-q, ű-b

Tags: macos, windows-10, keyboard, synergy, remote-control

I have [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) installed on 3 computers, all of them using **Hungarian** keyboard layout:

- **c1win** - Server - **Windows 10** - I am using the mouse and keyboard of this computer
- **c2ubu** - Client - **Ubuntu Linux** - This is a desktop PC remote controlled by c1win
- **c3osx** - Client - **OS X** - This is a MacBook Pro remote controlled by c1win

During remote controlling c3osx from c1win, the following anomalies happen:

- **ő-q** - when I press the "**ő**" key on my c1win a letter "**q**" is typed on c3osx
- **ű-b** - when I press the "**ű**" key on my c1win a letter "**b**" is typed on c3osx

On c2ubu everything works flawless, no such anomaly is observable, when I remote control it from c1win.

How can I make Synergy type the right characters on c3osx when I am remote controlling it from c1win ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue before using a Windows machine as server and a Linux machine as client. Sometimes after locking either machine my keyboard layout will change from English UK to French or Spanish. I normally restart the Server machine and it stops the issue temporarily.

As far as I know the development team for Synergy are working towards a fix for this bug, I'm not sure if they've released it yet though. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have a link/reference please to the problem the Synergy team is, or maybe, working on, related to this issue?  The problem highlighted by the original poster affects their (remote controlled) OSX but not (remote controlled) Linux, so would be good to have an answer that could explain this behaviour rather than speculating.

Comment: Restarting any of the Synergy applications (either server or client or both) yields no results, the anomaly remains.